# Is there a way to set a closed date on a case for my apex test?

Tags: apex, visualforce, closedate

I've recently built a VisualForce page which provides data about when cases have been closed etc.

I'm having trouble writing tests for this class due to the fact the field ClosedDate on the case object isn't writeable. I've noticed in the **Spring '16 release notes** we're getting `test.setCreatedDate`, but is there an equivalent for the case's closedDate field?

Can anybody suggest a workaround?

Comment: What kind of scenario do you really need to test?

Comment: you can update the status picklist and marked it as closed.

Comment: I'm counting the number of cases closed over a given period of time, so I need to insert 1 case with a closedDate of today, 1 with closedDate of yesterday, 1 with closedDate of 2 days ago... etc etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try spoofing your data. Here's a link:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181873&language=en_US